# AWS S3 CLI CP file and add metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Trying to copy a local file named test.txt to my s3 bucket and add metadata to the file.

But it always prints error:

**argument --metadata-directive: Invalid choice, valid choices are: COPY | REPLACE**

Is it possible to do this with the cp command, as I understand the docs it should be possible.
[AWS CLI CP DOCS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

This is the commands I've tried:

```
aws s3 cp test.txt to s3://a-bucket/test.txt --metadata x-amz-meta-cms-id:34533452

aws s3 cp test.txt to s3://a-bucket/test.txt --metadata-directive COPY --metadata x-amz-meta-cms-id:34533452

aws s3 cp test.txt to s3://a-bucket/test.txt --metadata-directive COPY --metadata '{"x-amz-meta-cms-id":"34533452"}'

aws s3 cp test.txt to s3://a-bucket/test.txt --metadata '{"x-amz-meta-cms-id":"34533452"}'
```

aws --version:
**aws-cli/1.9.7 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.1.0 botocore/1.3.7**

OS: **macOS Sierra version 10.12.1**

**Edit**

Worth mentioning is that uploading a file without the --metadata flag works fine.

Hmm, I've checked the help for my version of cli with `aws s3 cp help`
Turns out it does not list `--metadata` as an option, as the docs at the given link above does.

If runnig older version of aws cli

```
Use aws s3api put-object
```

How to upload a file to a bucket and add metadata:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket a-bucket --key test.txt --body test.txt --metadata '{"x-amz-meta-cms-id":"34533452"}'
```

Docs: [AWS S3API DOCS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

Comment: --metadata "filename=foobar.text"
worked for me on cli 1.16.40

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Indeed the support for metadata option has been added since [1.9.10](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/CLI/3108458396954945)

> `aws s3`  Added support for custom metadata in cp, mv, and sync.

so upgrading your aws cli to this version (or even better to latest) - and the `metadata` value needs to be a map so

```
aws s3 cp test.txt s3://a-bucket/test.txt --metadata '{"x-amz-meta-cms-id":"34533452"}'
```

Comment: Thanks mate! For some reason I read 1.9 as a higher version that 1.11

Comment: For me the command the json had to be inside ' '
aws s3 cp test.txt s3://a-bucket/test.txt --metadata '{"x-amz-meta-cms-id":"34533452"}'

Comment: hum ... ok will edit, I did not retry honestly - thought it worked without the quote. will edit so it works as an answer

Comment: I'm not sure you need the `x-amz-meta-` in the key name. This seems to get added automatically so you will end up with `x-amz-meta-x-amz-meta-cms-id`.

Comment: This works for me in linux but not in windows

Comment: The metadata can also be specified in the key/value notation: `--metadata KeyName1=string,KeyName2=string`

Comment: Can I add metadata to a folder or a file that is already on s3?

Answer (score 6):

Install `s3cmd` tools (*free*) and invoke like so:

```
s3cmd modify --add-header x-amz-meta-foo:bar s3://<bucket>/<object>
```

> With `x-amz-meta-foo:bar` header you will get `foo` as *key* and `bar` as *value* of that key.

Comment: Don't know why this was voted down, it seems to work (without copying the object)

`s3cmd modify --add-header x-amz-meta-foo:bar s3://ubookrcd/supplier-data/3101/campaigns/45367/<UUID>/original`

`aws s3api head-object --bucket ubookrcd --key supplier-data/3101/campaigns/45367/43/<UUID>/original
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes", 
    "ContentType": "image/jpeg", 
    "LastModified": "Tue, 05 Jun 2018 16:20:46 GMT", 
    "ContentLength": 5698870, 
    "ETag": "\"7a36ba8566eaf11abede38c0e3f01cc2\"", 
    "Metadata": {
        "qqfilename": "Image_23.jpg", 
        "foo": "bar"
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

There are special flags to set `Content-Type` and `Content-Encoding`

```
aws s3 cp test.gz. s3://a-bucket/test.gz --content-type application/octet-stream --content-encoding gzip
```

Answer (score 0):

There is bug with metadata directive "COPY" option.

`aws s3api copy-object --bucket testkartik --copy-source testkartik/costs.csv --key costs.csv --metadata-directive "COPY" --metadata "SomeKey=SomeValue"`

[image]

Below are the three steps to understand cli command with JQ workaround.

1. Install [JQ library](https://serverfault.com/questions/768026/how-to-install-jq-on-rhel6-5) to deal with json metadata using command line.
2. Read the existing metadata.

   `aws s3api head-object --bucket <bucket> --key <key> | jq '.Metadata' | jq --compact-output '. +{"new":"metadata", "another" : "metadata"}'`
3. Add new metadata.

   `aws s3api copy-object --bucket <bucket-name> --copy-source <bucket/key> --key <key> --metadata-directive "REPLACE" --metadata $(READ-THE-EXISTING-From-Step-2)`

   Complete command in one go.

   `aws s3api copy-object --bucket <bucket-name> --copy-source <bucket/key> --key <key> --metadata-directive "REPLACE" --metadata $(aws s3api head-object --bucket <bucket> --key <key> | jq '.Metadata' | jq --compact-output '. +{"new":"metadata", "another" : "metadata"}')`

Comment: Upvoted. This method works if for some reason you cannot use the new version of cp.