# "Invalid JSON" in AWS S3 pipeline when trying to add metadata to object

Tags: amazon-s3, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using bitbucket's pipeline to upload files to AWS S3. My bitbucket-pipelines.yml largely follows theis example [here](https://bitbucket.org/bitbucketpipelines/example-aws-s3-deploy/src/master/bitbucket-pipelines.yml). However, I'm also using `EXTRA_ARGS` param to specify several further options (excludes mostly), and I decided to also add there `--metadata` like so:

```
EXTRA_ARGS: "--size-only --exclude=README.md --metadata {\"testMeta\": \"testData\"}"
```

...and this works as expected, files uploaded have custom metadata added. But if I do something like this...:

```
EXTRA_ARGS: "--size-only --exclude=README.md --metadata {\"testMeta\": \"$BITBUCKET_COMMIT\"}"
```

namely, use one of Bitbucket's [default variables](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/), my pipeline output is as follows:

```
INFO: Starting deployment to S3...
aws s3 sync /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/public s3://[my-s3-name]/ --acl=public-read --size-only --exclude=README.md --metadata {"testMeta": "8cd36431ef08d5be22f28b2cfc63d0179db3618d"}
Error parsing parameter '--metadata': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded
JSON received: {"testMeta":
✖ Deployment failed.
```

So it seems that even though the variable is replaced with actual commit ID (as can be seen at the end of second line in the code above), for whatever reason it's not recognized as valid JSON. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem has to do with JSON, you could try the aws sync [--metadata Shorthand Syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html#options):

```
EXTRA_ARGS: "--size-only --exclude=README.md --metadata testMeta=$BITBUCKET_COMMIT"
```

Does that work?

Or try:

```
EXTRA_ARGS: "--size-only --exclude=README.md --metadata '{\"testMeta\": \"$BITBUCKET_COMMIT\"}'"
```

Note the extra `'` around the metadata parameter (via [Google "aws sync metadata"](https://www.google.com/search?q=aws%20sync%20metadata) > [AWS S3 CLI CP file and add metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626967/aws-s3-cli-cp-file-and-add-metadata)).

Comment: The shorthand syntax actually worked! Thank you very much!